Error in pip install mariadb on VS code in windows
I have to connect mariadb database with Python, for that I am trying to install mariadb on vs code, I am getting following error:
Collecting mariadb
  Using cached mariadb-1.1.10.tar.gz (84 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 3
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      Could not find InstallationDir of MariaDB Connector/C. Please make sure MariaDB Connector/C is installed or specify the InstallationDir of MariaDB Connector/C by setting the environment variable MARIADB_CC_INSTALL_DIR.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 3
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I have already installed the mariadb C- connector for windows (64- bit 86x) version: 3.3.11-GA

Try the recommended action in the error message: "specify the InstallationDir of MariaDB Connector/C by setting the environment variable MARIADB_CC_INSTALL_DIR."

How did you install MariaDB Connector/C. By downloading the MSI? If not, in which directory is C/C installed?

Did you follow each of the steps from the error? Specifically the environment variable? Otherwise, why not use sqlalchemy, pandas, or other database client is this specific one isn't working?

Set the MARIADB_CC_INSTALL_DIR environment variable to InstallationDir of MariaDB Connector/C.
